# Transfering windows-specific macro to run on Mac Excel

Tags: windows, macos, excel, vba

I've recently changed from a PC to a Mac. I run a lot of a macros and 99% of them are running fine, but I have one that doesn't work on a Mac.

It runs a set of other macros across all workbooks in a file. To do this it uses strings like this:

`Function BrowseFolder(Title As String, _
        Optional InitialFolder As String = vbNullString, _
        Optional InitialView As Office.MsoFileDialogView = _
            msoFileDialogViewList) As String`

When I try to run this on the Mac it comes back with an error:

> "compile error: variable not defined"

I wonder if anyone could help me with porting this macro over to run on Mac. It was built on Excel 2007 Windows and I'm trying to run it on Excel 2011 Mac.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetFolder(Optional strPath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
     If Not IsEmpty(strPath) Then
        .InitialFileName = strPath
    End If
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
 GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub test()
Dim v As Variant

'V = GetFolder()
v = BrowseFolder("Select folder")
End Sub

Function BrowseFolder(Title As String, _
        Optional InitialFolder As String = vbNullString, _
        Optional InitialView As Office.MsoFileDialogView = _
            msoFileDialogViewList) As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim InitFolder As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = Title
        .InitialView = InitialView
        If Len(InitialFolder) > 0 Then
            If Dir(InitialFolder, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
                InitFolder = InitialFolder
                If Right(InitFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                    InitFolder = InitFolder & "\"
                End If
                .InitialFileName = InitFolder
            End If
        End If
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
            Err.Clear
            v = .SelectedItems(1)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                v = vbNullString
            End If
        End With
    BrowseFolder = CStr(v)
End Function
```

Comment: "when i try to run this on the mac it come back with an error"... and that error would be...?

Comment: the error im getting is "compile error: variable not defined"

Comment: Which line in your code above does it indicate is the error?

Comment: i get it on line 31 `msoFileDialogViewList..`

Comment: See here for Mac examples: http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac.htm

Answer (score 1):

[`msoFileDialogViewList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432521%28v=office.12%29.aspx) refers to a specific view of the Windows standard file dialog. The Mac standard file dialog doesn't have equivalent modes; my guess is that the `InitialView` parameter either doesn't exist or is ignored on the Mac platform.

I'd advise either removing the parameter entirely or using the equivalent integer value (1) instead of the symbolic name.